# Missing Template Error when using Haml in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have been trying to use HAML with Rails 4 for an app but I'm getting a Missing Template Error [as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODgbC.jpg)

To get to this point, I followed the following steps:

1. Added the following gems to my Gemfile and `bundle install`
   [My Gemfile here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6MVr.jpg)
2. Added a pages controller [Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxsEx.jpg)
3. Updated `application.html.erb` to `application.html.haml` along with contents [Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJGin.jpg)
4. Added `home.html.haml` in pages view with code:

   `%h1 home page`

I'm not sure why it's not working. Having googled it, I found that `gem 'haml-rails'` needs to be added, which I did. Yet, I'm unable to see any change.

The tutorial I'm following is [here](https://iridakos.com/tutorials/2013/12/07/creating-a-simple-todo-part-1.html)

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us where have you put the `home.html.haml` file (in the project structure)?

Comment: Please dont include images, add actual code as text.

Comment: @Зелёный I tried many times to include it as code, it was not rendering properly. I had no choice but to put images.

Comment: @MrShemek `home.html.haml` is in `views` > `pages` folder

Answer (score 1):

I restarted the server and it seems to be working fine. Thank you all.